# C# Applications Dependencies Check

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2005, .net-3.5, compatibility

I have an application that i wrote in C# and it does databases. So to run this app on any machine i need **.NET 3.5** and **SQL Server 2005** installed. Is there a way that when the application starts. It first checks whether **SQL Server 2005** and **.Net 3.5** exist on the machine or not. If not then it may exit and if they do they may continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking for prerequisites is usually the job of an installer.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2005 can be verified, as installed SQL Server instances can be found in Services panel (which is also accessible via .NET).

It is not possible for a .NET 3.5 C# program to check whether .NET Framework is installed.

You'd better write native applications (in VC or else) to check for prerequisites.

Comment: cud this thing be written in C, i know C